# How can I play with friends?

Tags: battlefield-4

How do I make a squad with my friends so I can join a game together? I can't seem to find it and I looked for the past 30min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time (29th November 2013) this functions is not implemented. You can invite your friends to a server and when they join the game will try to balance you into the same team and same squad.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a group chat on Battlelog. Then if one of the group's members  is currently playing you'll be able to quick join his game.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will be able to get to that is to create a party chat in battlelog. You will be able to use a private voice channel and be able to easily join on each other. However, you can't join a server together, but the game will try to auto balance you to be able to play in the same squad. That will only apply to the friend you joined on and won't work for groups.

Comment: How do you create a group chat?

Comment: There should be an option in the com center, last time I used it though it was buggy.